# Creating multiple dataframes using list elements in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, list, ocr

I am applying OCR to  multiple PDF docs to extract relevant information & then save them in separate dataframes. But the last dataframe that's getting created with all the previous results. I understand that the loop has to be adjusted but failing to understand how to exactly resolve this. Below is my code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import pdfplumber
import re
import pandas as pd 

from collections import OrderedDict
def replace_all(text, dic):
for i, j in dic.items():
    text = text.replace(i, j)
return text

def admin_agreement():

    for page in pdf.pages:
        for w in admin_fee:
            Text = page.extract_text()
            if re.search(r"\b"+w+r"\b", Text, re.IGNORECASE):
                print(str("Administration fee") +" found on Page: "+ str(page) )

            page_num=int((replace_all(str(page), d)))



            final_page_num=page_num-1
            print("Text in " +invoice_pdf+"found on page number "+ str(final_page_num) )
            page = pdf.pages[final_page_num]
            text = page.extract_text(x_tolerance=2)
            lines=text.strip().split('\n')


            for line in lines:
                words=line.split()
                description=' '.join(words[1:])
                numbers=[word[1:] for word in words if '%' in word or '£' in word or '$' \
                                 in word or '€' in word or 'STF' in word]
                result.append((description,' of the '.join(numbers)))

            df=pd.DataFrame(result,columns=['AllFee','Numbers'])
            
            df.replace(r'', float('NaN'), regex = True)
            df=df.dropna(how='any',axis=0) 
            dfs[files]=df

return

pdfs=["test.pdf","AdministrationAgreementExecutedGreenEffectsInvestmentplc.pdf"]
result=[]
dfs={}
for files in pdfs:
    invoice_pdf=files
    print("Now processing " + invoice_pdf)
    os.system(f'ocrmypdf {invoice_pdf} --skip-text output.pdf')

    d = OrderedDict([('<Page:',''), (">", '')])

    admin_fee=["Administration fee","ADMINISTRATOR’S FEES","Fee of the administrator"]
    # Ask user for the type of agreement
    inp = input('What is the type of the agreement to be transcribed ?:\t')
    if inp == 'Administrative':
        with pdfplumber.open('output.pdf') as pdf:
        admin_agreement()
```

Comment: "But the last dataframe that's getting created with all the previous results" of course because the variables dfs and result are global variables. You need to declare these variables as locals to the function       admin_agreement()